# Trim last x seconds of audio files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of audio files from each of which I need to cut out the last 1 second. The audio files are of arbitrary lengths.

What is the best tool/way to do this?

I am somewhat familiar with ffmpeg, but AFAIK, it does not have a direct option to do this (the starting and ending times have to be provided with -ss and -to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by answers to other questions on this site, I was also able to make something up. This command can be passed to `find` as an `exec` option

```
ffmpeg -i FILE1.wma -ss 0 -to $(echo $(ffprobe -i FILE1.wma -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") - 1 | bc) -c copy FILE2.wma
```

The part in the middle `$(echo $(ffprobe -i FILE1.wma -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") - 1 | bc)` first gets the desired duration. The piping to `bc` is to compute in floating format. The output of this is then passed as the argument to `-to` in the main command.

To break down the long single line command above, for ease of comprehension:

```
    ffmpeg -i FILE1.wma -ss 0 -to
      $(echo 
        $(ffprobe -i FILE1.wma -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") 
        - 1 | bc
        )
    -c copy FILE2.wma
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a roundabout approach. Ingest the file twice, and offset the timestamps of the 2nd input by the duration at the end you wish to trim. Then pipe both streams to another ffmpeg instance with `-shortest` set. In the 2nd ffmpeg instance, save only the stream from the 2nd input.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -itsoffset 1 -i in.mp3 -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy -shortest -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -c copy -map 0:1 out.mp3`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mediainfo](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo) to get the duration (in ms) and then cut to duration - 1:

```
duration=$(mediainfo FILE.mp3 --Inform="Audio;%Duration%")
ffmpeg -to $(($duration / 1000 - 1)) -i FILE.mp3 -c copy FILE_NEW.mp3
```